# Why do we need to publish or deploy web services or WCF?

Tags: web-services, wcf

I am in the path of learning WebServices and WCF. So far I understand that webservice or Wcf contains web methods which can be consumed by client side or on the service side too. But my question is why do we need to publish/deploy a webservices or wcf in IIS or some other platform ? Cannot we just use them like methods in class.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: A WCF service needs to be **hosted** - either in IIS, a Windows Service or a self-hosted solution (like WinForms or a console app).  By definition, web service methods are not supposed to be used like a normal class (or library).  They're intended to be used (in most circumstances) by a remote client that generates a proxy (based on the WSDL of the service) to communicate (call) the methods in the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why do we need to publish/deploy a webservices or wcf

In order to make it available over internet (or) intranet (make it globally accessible). If you don't publish your service then it is not accessible by others since it can't be found/discovered.

Once you publish it, then your service can be discovers using the specific `server name + port` configuration where the service is listening for any request and your service client can use the generated `WSDL` file to create a proxy channel for consuming the service.